# Tweaking axis properties in a timeseries graph

Tags: r, data-visualization

The following code:

```
require(zoo)
data <- read.csv(file="summary.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
cum  = zoo(data$dcomp, as.Date(data$date))
data = zoo(data$compressed, as.Date(data$date))
data <- aggregate(data, identity, tail, 1)
cum  <- aggregate(cum, identity, sum, 1)
days = seq(start(data), end(data), "day")
data2 = na.locf(merge(data, zoo(,days)))

pdf(file='timeseries.pdf',width=9,height=5)
par(bty = 'n')
plot(data2,xlab='',ylab='entropy (bytes)',axes=FALSE)
axis(side = 2, at=c(991, 20000, 40000, 53048))
axis(side = 2, at=c(10000, 30000),labels=FALSE)
lines(cum,type="h",lwd=0.3,col=rgb(0.64,0.08,0.00))
axis.Date(side = 1, days, at=c("2007-07-25", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-06-21"))
```

Yields the following Graph:

[image]

The questions (all related to the bottom axis) are:

1. How can I make it display '2007/07' and '2010/06' in the beginning and end labels?
2. How can I make it to automatically add minor ticks to the months (without labels)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick suggestions:

1. `axis.Date()` has a format field, set it to `"%Y/%m" to get '2007/07' (but then for all labels)
2. See `help(axTicks)` and `help(rug)` which should help you.

Also try the [xts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) package which extends the [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package. You may find reading the source for the plotting functions in both packages helpful.

Comment: Your first suggestions worked great. Your second, I wasn't able to achieve what I wanted. Could you give me an example? Thx.